# Make selective ListView and send parameters onclick to element of ListView

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-activity

I have 2 2D arrays and one of the columns (`id`) is a member in both arrays. I would like to construct a `Listview` using:

- the `name` value in the first array
- the `id` value in the first array (where all `id` values are unique)
- the `id` value in the second array (where `id` values may be the same)

For example:

**First array (`name`|`id`):**

```
dkkgg 2
abcd 1
dffs 4
gsf 3
```

---

**Second array (`info`|`id`):**

```
infoddf 2
glhfd 1
vv 2
```

---

**ListView:**

```
dkkgg
dkkgg 
abcd
```

When clicking on an item in the `Listview`, I don't know how to send parameters (other values from the first and second arrays) to the new activity. If I click on the first `Listview` element, I get a new activity (`infoddf`), a new activity (`vv`) for the second element, and a new activity (`glhfd`) for the third element.